# Converting subquery to CTE

Tags: sql, oracle, common-table-expression

Please how can i rewrite this query using cte

```
select distinct(ref_device_id)
from heart_beat
where ref_device_id in (select DEVICE_ID
                        from enrollment_ref er
                        join node n on n.enrollment_ref = er.id)
```

Comment: What have you tried?  This is not particularly tricky.

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function. Also, what is wrong with the existing query? How do you expect a sub-query factoring clause (a.k.a. CTE) to improve the query compared to using `IN` or `EXISTS`?

Comment: I'm learning how to use CTEs so I wanted to try using it on that query sort of like an example. but I think I know this one is optimal for what I was trying to achieve with that query.

Answer (score 1):

You could use:

```sql
WITH cte ( device_id ) AS (
  SELECT device_id
  FROM   enrollment_ref er
         INNER JOIN node n
         ON ( n.enrollment_ref = er.id )
)
SELECT DISTINCT
       ref_device_id
FROM   heart_beat
WHERE  ref_device_id in ( SELECT device_id FROM cte );
```

or

```sql
WITH cte ( ref_device_id ) AS (
  SELECT DISTINCT
         ref_device_id
  FROM   heart_beat
  WHERE  ref_device_id in (
           SELECT device_id
           FROM   enrollment_ref er
                  INNER JOIN node n
                  ON ( n.enrollment_ref = er.id )
         )
)
SELECT ref_device_id
FROM   cte;
```

Comment: oh, I thought I couldn't specify a join in a CTE..I saw that when I tried searching online ...it's kind of obvious I'm a very huge novice...thank you..this worked